# Looking for an utility function for which St. Petersburgh paradox becomes unbounded

Tags: functions, derivatives, paradoxes, utility

A professor has explained to my class [St. Petersburgh paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) and has introduced the concept of [utility function](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/072915/what-utility-function-and-how-it-calculated.asp#:%7E:text=Utility%20function%20measures%20consumers%27%20preferences%20for%20bundles%20of%20goods%20or,Oregon%20State%20University.).

The professor then asked us to find an utility function with a positive first derivative and a negative second derivative to obtain a cost functional with a positive first derivative and a negative second derivative.

I have found [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1578.pdf). and the own Wikipedia page of the paradox, in which is said

> For any unbounded utility function, one can find a lottery that allows for a variant of the St. Petersburg paradox, as was first pointed out by Menger

It is clear that my professor is talking about a logarithm, whose first derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$, positive for all positive numbers, and the second is $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, negative for all real numbers. However, I have no idea on how to obtain an unbounded logarithm function.

Comment: What do you mean? The logarithm is unbounded.

Comment: Yes, but if I calculate the expected value of the logarithm of the gains is $\sum_1^\infty\frac{ln(2^n)}{2^n}$, which is bounded

Comment: Is your question about the quote from the Wikipedia article? You just have to modify the payout so it's $2^{2^n}$. You can do this same trick for any unbounded utility function.

Comment: Then, should I then do  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ln(2^{2^n})}{2^n}$ does this thing has a positive first derivative and a negative second?

Comment: I don't understand what the two parts of your question have to do with each other. That expression you've written down is not a function, it's just an infinite sum, which diverges. It doesn't have a derivative.